# oracle : Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a problem, I don't understand why do I have this error

Here's the code

```
        CREATE TABLE Deposit
        (   ac_no Int(15),
        customer_name Varchar(35),
        branch_name Varchar(30),
        Amount Int(10,2),
        credit_date Date
        );
```

Comment: INT(10,2) looks very suspicious. Could you please try NUMERIC(10,2)

Comment: [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0BC16006-32F1-42B1-B45E-F27A494963FF) is a synonym for `number(38)`. Also by definition `int` is an integer number, it even cannot have a scale.

Answer (score 6):

Because integers don't have size nor precision.

Also, use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR` (that's not an *error*, but Oracle recommends so).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE deposit
  2  (
  3     ac_no           INT,
  4     customer_name   VARCHAR2 (35),
  5     branch_name     VARCHAR2 (30),
  6     amount          INT,
  7     credit_date     DATE
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Littlefoot already said, `INT` data type has no precision or scale. If you want precision and scale in your numbers, then use `number` data type instead.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE deposit
  2  (
  3     ac_no           number(15),
  4     customer_name   VARCHAR2 (35),
  5     branch_name     VARCHAR2 (30),
  6     amount          number(10,2),
  7     credit_date     DATE
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```